# How to create Multi-Role Manager in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I need to do a project  in Android. I was asked to create Multi-Role Manager for Wi-FI, Wi- Fi-Direct and Hotspot that will work in Parallel.
Today we can't use t'wo or three actions at the same time, one action cancel another action.

I do'nt know even how to start this, do i need to change the something in the system,
I found the link below but i do'nt know how i can use it.

somebody have any idea how to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/WifiService.java

Comment: Do you know if that's possible at all, since the phone has only 1 wi-fi module, maybe it's impossible because of hardware? I don't know that though